# How to call applescript method from bash script?

Tags: bash, applescript

i have an applescript method deleteFile(file) with parameter which file to delete. I want to call this method from bash script, but i cannot find a way to do that. Is it possible and how can i do that ?

Comment: possible cross site duplicate : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103621/run-applescript-from-bash-script

Comment: i have an parameter in my applescript method and there isnt any helpful answer

Comment: Why was this tagged iOS? Please tag properly.

Comment: If you're already running a `bash` script, why not just delete the file using `rm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the man page for [**`osascript`**](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html). In Terminal: `man osascript`

> **NAME**
>              **osascript** — execute AppleScripts and other OSA language scripts
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>             **osascript** [ **-l** language] [ **-s** flags] [ **-e** statement | programfile] [argument ...]

Note: Depending on the actual *code* content of `programfile`, I've seen `osascript` not be able to process some *code* when saved in the **.scpt** file format. In cases such as this, saving it as plain text usually resolves the issue.

Comment: @Bozhidar Marinov, you said "I found other way - osascript + name of the script file + parameters, without any " "", ................. Yes that is shown in the man page example which I linked in the answer, `osascript a.scpt world`. Looking at the SYNOPSIS in the name page, that corresponds to: `osascript programfile argument`